# Is this a bug in the flutter? DecoratedBox & IconButton

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, iconbutton

I wrapped the IconButton by DecoredBox, why splash not show correctly?

[image]

is this is bug or Or I'm wrong?
Does anyone have a solution?

```
BoxDecoration decoration = BoxDecoration(
      color: theme.backgroundColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
      border: Border.symmetric(
          horizontal: BorderSide(color: borderColor, width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
          vertical: BorderSide(color: borderColor, width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
      ),
    );

DecoratedBox(
      decoration: decoration,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4, vertical: 0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          textDirection: direction,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            searchIcon,
            Expanded(
              child: input,
            ),
            clearIcon,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: please edit your question to include you code

Comment: it's not a bug. Ink splashes always are at the "bottom layer" of your material app, so you have to either make your other components transparent instead of that white background (on the text field), or you have to wrap a `InkWell(` widget on top of that white background. I'm sure there are some other work arounds as well, but those are the easy ones.

Comment: It's pretty obvious as to why it has to be so, because the splashes almost always are larger than the widget producing them.  And layering them on top would require some advanced masking. Of course, using inkwells inside of widgets often causes clipping issues instead. So you have choose your poison.

Comment: Yes. My problem is not the protrusion. My problem is why I do not have  splash inside box.

Comment: Because the splash is behind box. Try an inkwell. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html  ...and the ink (sorry about that) https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Ink-class.html

Comment: The splash is behind the box !! How ?  This is wrapped by DecoratedBox.

Answer (score 1):

The splash is not visible because you have set a color for the `BoxDecoration`.

try the following solution

```
Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12),
              ),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      splashRadius: 25,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      splashRadius: 25,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Comment: or you can wrap the ```DecoratedBox``` with a ```Material``` widget, remove the color of the ```'BoxDecoration``` and instead set the color to ```Material```

Comment: Yes, Material is The way of salvation. Thanks to both.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

I used of Material().

Updated code:

```
DecoratedBox(
      decoration: decoration,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4, vertical: 0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          textDirection: direction,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                type: MaterialType.circle,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                borderOnForeground: true,
                elevation: 0,
                child: searchIcon,
              ),
            Expanded(
              child: input,
            ),
            Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                type: MaterialType.circle,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                borderOnForeground: true,
                elevation: 0,
                child: clearIcon,
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is splash effect I also used IconButton Widget I also have same issue but when I used Inkwell Widget my splash effect doesn't show and my splash effect above of the textfield. try below code instead of IconButton hope its help to you

[InkWell Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) and you also used [GesterDectector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) also

```
suffixIcon: InkWell( 
   child:Icon(Icons.search),
   onTap:(){},
 ),
```

#### **If you Need Splash**

try below code , pressed on search icon and see the splash like below image I have displayed

```
TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        suffixIcon: IconButton(onPressed: (){},
        icon:Icon(Icons.search),
       ),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
    )
```

When I use IconButton Widget my splash result like ->  [image]

Comment: I replaced IconButton with (InkWell) now I no longer have any splash. I need a splash.  If I make the background of the DecoratedBox transpaent, a splash is displayed. But I do not want to make the background transpaent.